# Formatting data in pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas, import-from-csv

I attempted to run the code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=',', header=None, names=['datatable', 'col'])

def replace_letter(group):
    letters = group.isin(['T', 'Q'])              # select letters
    group[letters] = int(group[~letters].max()) + 1  # replace by next max
    return group


df['col'] = df.groupby('datatable').transform(replace_letter)
print df
```

On the data:

```
DatatableA,1
DatatableA,2
DatatableA,3
DatatableA,4
DatatableA,5
DatatableB,1
DatatableB,6
DatatableB,T
DatatableB,3
DatatableB,4
DatatableB,5
DatatableB,2
DatatableC,3
DatatableC,4
DatatableC,2
DatatableC,1
DatatableC,Q
DatatableC,5
DatatableC,T
```

Hoping to produce the following

```
DatatableA,1
DatatableA,2
DatatableA,3
DatatableA,4
DatatableA,5
DatatableB,1
DatatableB,6
DatatableB,7
DatatableB,3
DatatableB,4
DatatableB,5
DatatableB,2
DatatableC,3
DatatableC,4
DatatableC,2
DatatableC,1
DatatableC,6
DatatableC,5
DatatableC,6
```

and I received the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/test.py", line 11, in <module>
    df['col'] = df.groupby('datatable').transform(replace_letter)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 1981, in transform
    res = path(group)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 2006, in <lambda>
    slow_path = lambda group: group.apply(lambda x: func(x, *args, **kwargs), axis=self.axis)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4416, in apply
    return self._apply_standard(f, axis)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4491, in _apply_standard
    raise e
ValueError: ("invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'col'", u'occurred at index col')
```

I am trying to replace the letter T or any other letter for that matter with the next highest integer for that table. The first table contains no errors, the second table contains 1 T and the third contains 2 x t's.
Is there something I have used in correctly, but I have been meaning to use pandas more, as the library seems so useful for data manipulations.

#### Edit 1

It was indeed an issue with having a header, simply changing `header` to `=True` made it work. However I still cannot get this code to do what I want it to do.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=',', header=True, names=['datatabletest', 'col'])

def replace_letter(group):
    letters = group.isin(['T', 'Q'])              # select letters
    group[letters] = int(group[~letters].max()) + 1  # replace by next max
    return group

df["duplicate"] = df['col']
print df
df['col'] = df.groupby('datatabletest').transform(replace_letter)
print df
```

I was hoping to duplicate the column so I have a copy of the original, changing the letters in only one of the columns. Can you see what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I guess your csv file in fact contains a header, that is its first line is `datatable,col`. Then, when you specify `header=None`, this header is loaded as a first row of a dataframe. You should either skip header with `skiprows` paramether, or read it from file removing `header=None`.

Compare those two examples:

```
>>> s = "DatatableA,1"
>>> df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s),  sep=',', header=None, 
...          names=['datatable', 'col'])
>>> df['col'] = df.groupby('datatable').transform(replace_letter)
>>> df
    datatable  col
0  DatatableA    1
```

But

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv(StringIO('datatable,col\n'+s),  sep=',',
...          header=None, names=['datatable', 'col'])
>>> df['col'] = df.groupby('datatable').transform(replace_letter)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
ValueError: ("invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'col'", u'occurred at index col')
```

Comment: I have edited my code, to show a secondary error I encountered.

Comment: @AEA For a secondary error, you should not edit original question but start a new one, this way you keep one problem per question and answer, making it more usable for further reference. 

For your second issue you can use `df['dup'] = df.groupby('datatabletest')['col'].transform(replace_letter)`, but I  don't want to add this to the answer for the reasons stated above.

Comment: Thanks alko, I did consider it, thought it might get marked as duplicate if I did though. Many thanks.